# Why can't I use the increase/decrease functions on my JavaScript localStorage shoppping cart?

Tags: javascript

I cannot increase or decrease item quantity in my JavaScript Shopping cart nor can I delete items off the cart. It's displaying the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'inCart' of undefined
    at HTMLElement.<anonymous>
```

It's undefined, yet I seemed to have declared it correctly and have no errors with the objects in my cart Products (as seen below)

```
let products = [
  {
    name: "Metal Straw",
    tag: "metalstraw",
    price: 4.95,
    inCart: 0
  },
  {
    name: "Rain Catchment System",
    tag: "rainwatercatcher",
    price: 449.95,
    inCart: 0
  },
  {
    name: "Copper Water Bottle",
    tag: "copper",
    price: 4.95,
    inCart: 0
  },
  {
    name: "Rattan Tote Bag",
    tag: "tote",
    price: 2.95,
    inCart: 0
  }
]
```

JS Code tied to it:

```
function manageQuantity() {
    let decreaseButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.fa-minus-circle');
    let increaseButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.fa-plus');
    let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
    let currentQuantity = 0;
    let currentProduct = "";
    cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);
    console.log(cartItems);

    for(let i=0; i < decreaseButtons.length; i++) {
        decreaseButtons[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
            currentQuantity = decreaseButtons[i].parentElement.querySelector('span').textContent;
            console.log(currentQuantity);
            currentProduct = decreaseButtons[i].parentElement.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.querySelector('span').textContent.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '').trim();
            console.log(currentProduct);

            if( cartItems[currentProduct].inCart > 1 ) {
                cartItems[currentProduct].inCart -= 1;
                cartNumbers( cartItems[currentProduct], "decrease" );
                totalCost( cartItems[currentProduct], "decrease" );
                localStorage.setItem('productsInCart', JSON.stringify(cartItems));
                displayCart();
            }
        });
    }

    for(let i=0; i < increaseButtons.length; i++) {
        increaseButtons[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
            console.log("Increase button");
            currentQuantity = increaseButtons[i].parentElement.querySelector('span').textContent;
            console.log(currentQuantity);

            currentProduct = increaseButtons[i].parentElement.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.querySelector('span').textContent.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '').trim();
            console.log(currentProduct);


                cartItems[currentProduct].inCart += 1;
                cartNumbers( cartItems[currentProduct]);
                totalCost( cartItems[currentProduct]);
                localStorage.setItem('productsInCart', JSON.stringify(cartItems));
                displayCart();

        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you handle the case when your CartNumbers is empty ?

Comment: @VoQuocThang Nothing is displayed when my cart Numbers are empty

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the "cartItems" variable is an array, and you are trying to use a string as an index. What I'm guessing you want to do is get the item from the array that has its "name" property match a given string. In that case, do this:

```js
cartItems.find((x) => x.name === OTHER_NAME)
```

Comment: Okay, I'll replace let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart') with this one

Comment: I meant that you should replace "cartItems[currentProduct].inCart += 1;" with "cartItems.find((x) => x.name === currentProduct).inCart++;".